# URL forwarding forcing IE into quirks mode. Server issue?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

I have a basic website that I am having some IE9 Quirks Mode issues with.

The site is an OpenCart installation at "http://www.darrendifilippo.com.au/top-fuel-funny-car".  The client wants this site to be redirected to from another domain "http://www.dpe.net.au".

The company that hosts the website at "http://www.darrendifilippo.com.au" is a different company to the one that "http://www.dpe.net.au" is held with.

A URL forward is set up to do this redirection.  This forwarding is set up from within my account with the domain company (no access to ftp for htaccess or anything like that).

My problem is this: I uploaded the site onto the "darrendifilippo" server with the intent to go live and complete everything.  When I go to "http://www.dpe.net.au" and click on the Top Fuel button to be taken to the new site ("http://www.darrendifilippo.com.au/top-fuel-funny-car") Internet Explorer displays the site in bloody quirks mode.

I checked my DOCTYPEs and they seem ok.  I also have the XUA hack running.

I was a bit confused that when I navigated straight to "http://www.darrendifilippo.com.au/top-fuel-funny-car" without going through the URL forwarding, the websites Page Default changes to IE 9 Standards Mode.

I thought this could be a server issue?  Perhaps the forwarding server is switching everything to Quirks Mode.

It just doesn't add up!

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>

<head>
```

---

A few days later....

OK, so the plot has thickened somewhat..

I've found that something is COMMENTING OUT my Doctype declaration when my web page is navigated to from the dpe.net.au domain.  When navigated to directly (darrendifilippo.com.au/top-fuel-funny-car/) my code remains unfettered.

This commenting out only displays in the Developer Tools window.  Viewing the source of both examples shows no difference.  I've attached images below..  The first image is my code as it should be when all displays well (not sure what the empty text nodes are but anyway..), the second shows something commenting out my Doctype and adding in a Frameset.

[image: This is my code as it should be when everything displays fine]

[image: Something is changing my code! You can see there's been a frameset added and my Doctype is commented out]

If anyone has any ideas what this could be, help would be appreciated.  I still think this is a server side issue, maybe someone set up a default document declaration for the redirect or created some kind of arrangement with a frameset that gets slapped on every document ... I dunno..

Comment: The company that the domain "dpe.net.au" is registered with is "enetica.com.au".  Just out of curiosity I wanted to see if their OWN website renders in quirks mode... it does.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an html 4 strict dtd, you should avoid self-closing tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

or better yet, change your doctype to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I am not sure if that is your issue, but it is definitely related to your markup.  Nothing on the server-side would lead IE to render in quirksmode unless of course it changed your markup.

Comment: But the markup renders fine in IE when viewed without the redirection.  Quirks only turns on when the redirection is used.

Comment: @DeanActual When you do a view-source on each, is the rendered markup identical?